# Delete based on composite key from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been really reluctant to post this because I feel it's a common issue, but I can not seem to find an answer that applies to this situation... (maybe I'm just a really bad googler).

I have two identical tables(column wise, not data), table1 and table2. I wish to delete the records in table1 in which the composite key (col1, col2) exists in both tables. Here is what I have, which seems correct to me, but is throwing an error.

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (**Col1**, Col2) IN
(SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
    AND a.Col2 = b.Col2)
```

Error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 212 An expression of non-boolean
>   type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

I have put two `*` around the portion of code which has 'Red error squiggles'.

Comment: I believe this is SQL-SERVER?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have been more specific. Here at work we just refer to SQL-SERVER as SQL and Oracle as Oracle.

Comment: Since Oracle is a lot "older" than sql-server, weird convention but... if it make your boss happy and you richer, why not!

Comment: It's easy to see how that came about though, SQL is part of the name of SQL Server, so it was simply abbreviated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be cleanly performed using `JOIN` with your [`DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

```
DELETE a
FROM 
    Table1 a 
    JOIN Table2 b
        ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
        AND a.Col2 = b.Col2
```

Comment: This solution works, but I'm hoping you could explain why mine didn't work. I have seen solutions to similar problems which use the `(col1, col2)` syntax.

Comment: @Jeff that's valid for Oracle, but not Sql Server... they use slightly different dialects of Sql and aren't always interchangeable.

Comment: That makes sense. I could have sworn I used this syntax in SQL-Server at some point, but I'm probably wrong. It's a mess trying to keep the syntax straight between SQL-Server, MySQL, and Oracle. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Which DBMS is it? If it is in oralce then pairwise comparison should work.

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (Col1, Col2) IN
(SELECT Col1, Col2
 FROM Table2)
```

If it is SQL server then Michael's solution should work.

Comment: This also works in HSQLDB: `delete from table1 where (col1, col2, col3) in (select col1, col2, col3 from someview123 where ...)`

Comment: Does not work in MSSQL 2014. But Michael Fredrickson solution works

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the answers cover the general case, so I'll put mine:

You must concat your fields into one field:

Ex.:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE concat(Col1,'******',Col2) 
 IN (SELECT concat(a.Col1,'******',b.Col2) 
FROM Table1 a 
JOIN Table2 b
ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
AND a.Col2 = b.Col2))
```